# How to tell which induction cookware is most efficient in conducting heat?

Tags: induction

As above. I am looking for a durable water kettle (preferably stainless steel 304) that is super efficient in conducting heat when on induction cooker. How do I tell which brand/model will conduct heat the fastest without doing the actual test?

Comment: Is your actual goal to boil water as fast as possible?

Comment: Specifically on an induction cooker. I don't like the idea of an electric kettle because the bottom surface is hard to maintain.

Comment: Yes, of course, you were clear you want induction. It's just that heat conduction is a slightly indirect way to ask about rapid boiling, because there may be other factors, so if you meant boiling as fast as possible you might want to just say so in the question.

Comment: Heat conduction is not what matters much with induction cookware...

Answer (score 1):

Your rule of thumb for induction cookware of any sort is that if a magnet will stick to it, it will work. If you can get to a store that has the kettles you are interested in, bring a magnet with you to test the various models. The better the magnet sticks, the better off you probably are.

I would give a couple of extra things some consideration.  The heavier the pot, the more consistent the heat, though most induction cooktops are really good at maintaining a temperature.  Second, go with stainless if at all possible.  It's so much easier to clean and maintain.

**Edit:**

Just climbed out of another internet rabbit hole.  Induction cookware works because of a current induced into metal that does not conduct electricity well.  Iron works great because it is not a totally efficient conductor.  Stainless steel, because of the different alloys, does not always work on an induction cooktop.  Clad pots and pans that have layers of ferric metals sandwiched between layers of better conductive metals can give you a balance of heating ability and conductivity.  All of this, though, can in general be boiled down to: Heavy is good, Magnetic is Good, Stainless is Good. You can check these in store before you buy.

If you are looking to buy online, you face a different set of problems.  An "Induction Ready" label is a place to start.

**Second Edit**:

[Fantastic Information](http://theinductionsite.com/induction-cookware.php) here.  Tells you a lot more about how the whole shebang works, so you can decide what you will require in a Kettle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answers the question.

Comment: It's not very scientific if I were to gauge the magnetic strength with my bare hands alone. There should be another way out. Consistency isn't my concern here. Conductivity is.

Comment: @Cindy, if the pan is not made of a magnetic metal, it won't work on an induction cooktop.  That is the first test.  The strength of the magnet is a rough guideline on how well it is likely to work on an induction surface.  multiple layers usually increase heat conductivity over the whole surface.  Good weight means thermal mass, which means heat is maintained more smoothly.  Cast Iron is great on induction cooktops, but is hard to maintain.  The point is, you can do these checks in store. before you buy.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the actual formulae required, and I don't know enough about metallurgy to be much more specific, I do know that I can take a rare earth magnet to Bed, Bath, and Beyond and stick it to various pans.  The ones that the magnet stuck to best were the ones that worked best when I got them home.  Best results came from pots that had some mass to them, and finally, stainless is just easiest to clean.  It's all based on experience.  As to conductivity, Induction cooktops rely on a material NOT being too conductive.  That's why copper don't work

Comment: In the question, the OP stated that he would prefer stainless steel. So, it's not a question of which metal to choose. And I agree with his comment about gauging the magnetic strength with bare hands. I expect that, unless there was a huge difference from one kettle to another, it would be difficult to feel the difference.

Comment: @Cindi, you would be surprised.  On one shopping trip I tested maybe a dozen different saucepans.  Looking at Stainless specifically, the alloys vary widely.  Of the dozen, the magnet barely clung to 4, on I think 3 others, it didn't stick at all.  there were a few that it stuck tight too.  after that it was down to other considerations

Comment: Did you also research online or based your buying decision on testing in store? I find it difficult to find an induction cookware specialised website that independently reviews these cookware (other than typical places like Amazon, which can be based and subjective). Lastly, which model did you buy eventually?

Comment: I bought based on testing in the store for the saucepan.  I ended up buying a Cuisinart pan from Wal Mart was the best balance of price and weight.  I have a NuWave, and to be honest, the best pans for that are the ones that came with the cooktop.  We also have a set of Lodge brand Cast Iron that works really well, but cast iron is more work to maintain than I usually want to bother with.  Did you see the link I just included in my edit?